# excluding dups which are lower than max values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following simple table (Table1), where each row is a student_ID and their name, and each student has one or multiple wins (Wins). I would like to output: Student_ID, Student_name, count of Wins, sorted by count of Wins (descending) and then Student_ID (ascending), excluding those students who have the same count of Wins which is less than the max of the Wins (i.e.5). In other words, Lizzy and Mark have the same count of wins, and 3 is lower than 5, so the output will exclude the two students, Lizzy and Mark.

From comments: "Betty, David and Cathy should be excluded", also.

Table1:

| student_id | student_name | wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | YES |
| 1 | John | YES |
| 1 | John | YES |
| 1 | John | YES |
| 1 | John | YES |
| 2 | Brandon | YES |
| 2 | Brandon | YES |
| 2 | Brandon | YES |
| 2 | Brandon | YES |
| 2 | Brandon | YES |
| 3 | Lizzy | YES |
| 3 | Lizzy | YES |
| 3 | Lizzy | YES |
| 4 | Mark | YES |
| 4 | Mark | YES |
| 4 | Mark | YES |
| 5 | Betty | YES |
| 6 | David | YES |
| 7 | Cathy | YES |
| 8 | Joe | YES |
| 8 | Joe | YES |

Desired output:

| student_id | student_name | cnt_wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 5 |
| 2 | Brandon | 5 |
| 8 | Joe | 2 |

Here is my SQL in Oracle. I can't figure out what went wrong. The log says "(SELECT b.cnt_wins, count(b.student_id) has too many values".

```
WITH st_cte AS
(SELECT student_id, student_name, count(wins) cnt_wins
FROM Table1
GROUP BY student_id, student_name
ORDER BY count(wins) DESC, student_id)
SELECT *
FROM st_cte a
WHERE a.cnt_wins not in
(SELECT b.cnt_wins, count(b.student_id)
 FROM st_cte b
 WHERE b.cnt_wins <
 (SELECT max(c.cnt_wins) FROM st_cte c)
 GROUP BY b.cnt_wins
 HAVING count(b.student_id) > 1);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: It's not clear why you wouldn't also exclude Betty, David, and Cathy, since they also have the same count of wins and with a count of less than the max.  So I just assumed you wanted anyone with one win to be in the result.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, Betty, David and Cathy should be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many values selected inside the 'in' select:

```
WHERE a.cnt_wins -- 1 value
  not in
       (SELECT b.cnt_wins, count(b.student_id) -- 2 values
         FROM st_cte b
```

you shoud either do :

```
WHERE a.cnt_wins not in
       (SELECT b.cnt_wins
         FROM st_cte ...
```

or

```
 WHERE (a.cnt_wins, count(something)) not in
        (SELECT b.cnt_wins, count(b.student_id)
          FROM st_cte ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on updated requirements...

The requirement was ambiguous in that Betty, David, and Cathy seem to also meet the criteria to be removed from the result.  This requirement was clarified and those rows should have been removed.

Logic has been added to allow only all `max_cnt` rows, plus any students with a unique count.

Also note that if `wins` can be any other non-null value, `COUNT(wins)` is not correct.

Given all that, maybe something like this is a starting point:

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6da233bbd4f533f6ea765d26d84013dc)

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT student_id, student_name
             , COUNT(wins) cnt_wins
             , MAX(COUNT(wins)) OVER () AS max_cnt
          FROM Table1
         GROUP BY student_id, student_name
     )
   , cte2 AS (
        SELECT cte.*
             , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cnt_wins) AS cnt_students
          FROM cte
     )
SELECT student_id, student_name, cnt_wins
  FROM cte2
 WHERE max_cnt = cnt_wins
    OR cnt_students = 1
 ORDER BY cnt_wins DESC, student_id
;
```

and to handle `wins` that can be other non-null values:

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT student_id, student_name
             , COUNT(CASE WHEN wins = 'YES' THEN 1 END) cnt_wins
             , MAX(COUNT(CASE WHEN wins = 'YES' THEN 1 END)) OVER () AS max_cnt
          FROM Table1
         GROUP BY student_id, student_name
     )
   , cte2 AS (
        SELECT cte.*
             , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cnt_wins) AS cnt_students
          FROM cte
     )
SELECT student_id, student_name, cnt_wins
  FROM cte2
 WHERE max_cnt = cnt_wins
    OR cnt_students = 1
 ORDER BY cnt_wins DESC, student_id
;
```

Result (with data to test the new requirement, one student (Joe) with unique counts (2)):

| STUDENT_ID | STUDENT_NAME | CNT_WINS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 5 |
| 2 | Brandon | 5 |
| 8 | Joe | 2 |

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    Student_ID   int
  , Student_Name VARCHAR2(20)
  , Wins         VARCHAR2(10)
);


BEGIN
-- Assume only wins are stored.

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 1, 'John', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 1, 'John', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 1, 'John', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 1, 'John', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 1, 'John', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 2, 'Brandon', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 2, 'Brandon', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 2, 'Brandon', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 2, 'Brandon', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 2, 'Brandon', 'YES');

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 3, 'Lizzy', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 3, 'Lizzy', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 3, 'Lizzy', 'YES');

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 4, 'Mark', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 4, 'Mark', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 4, 'Mark', 'YES');

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 5, 'Betty', 'YES');

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 6, 'David', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 7, 'Cathy', 'YES');

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 8, 'Joe', 'YES');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 8, 'Joe', 'YES');
END;
/
```

Correction to the original query in the question:

```
WITH st_cte AS
  (SELECT student_id, student_name, count(wins) cnt_wins
     FROM Table1
    GROUP BY student_id, student_name
    ORDER BY count(wins) DESC, student_id
  )
SELECT *
  FROM st_cte a
 WHERE a.cnt_wins not in
   (SELECT b.cnt_wins
      FROM st_cte b
     WHERE b.cnt_wins < (SELECT max(c.cnt_wins) FROM st_cte c)
     GROUP BY b.cnt_wins
    HAVING count(b.student_id) > 1
   )
;
```

Comment: You are right. Sorry, Betty, David and Cathy should be excluded.

Comment: Why did you say "if wins can be any other non-null value, COUNT(wins) is not correct"? @Jon Armstrong

Comment: Assume Betty, David, and Cathy each has a different count of wins,  which should end up being included, how do I modify your codes? Thanks!

Comment: @SilverSpringbb Because `COUNT` will count any non-null values, not just those that are 'YES'.  The second query I showed handles counting just those rows that are 'YES'.  Removing the `cnt_wins = 1` will remove the other incorrect rows.

Comment: @SilverSpringbb Logic has been updated.  See the second query to also handle counting only the 'YES' rows properly.  Given the current data (all 'YES' rows) the two queries produce the same result.